# Docker-compose does not expose port of both services (with example to reproduce)

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I am confused why docker-compose exposes the ports in different ways.
Maybe someone can explain me this bahavior?

- On my machine the port 3306 from the mariadb container is available by `127.0.0.1:3306`

  - This is as expected
- On my machine the port 29000 is **not** available by `127.0.0.1:29000`

  - This is **not** as expected. It is available by the ip of the docker-container: `172.17.0.32:80`
- I do not get any errors. As long as I am using the docker web container address everything works fine.
- The Webserver is able to communicate with the mariadb by using `mariadb.devlocal:3306`

Here is my docker-compose YAML file:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.4
    restart: always
    networks:
      some-network:
        aliases:
          - mariadb.devlocal
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  web:
    image: nginx:1.18
    hostname: webserver.devlocal
    networks:
      - some-network
    ports:
      - "29000:80"
    depends_on:
      - db

networks:
  some-network:
```

You can try the example by executing `docker-compose run web`

Executing `docker-compose ps` shows this:

```
                  Name                               Command             State           Ports         
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
docker-compose-test_db_1                   docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld   Up      0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp
docker-compose-test_web_run_23ef735f9a70   nginx -g daemon off;          Up      80/tcp
```

Executing `netstat -tulpen | grep -i docker` shows this:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          131920      22696/docker-proxy
```

I am using this docker-compose version:

```
docker-compose version 1.23.2, build unknown
docker-py version: 3.7.3
CPython version: 2.7.12
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
```

Comment: Did you get any errors? are you sure that everything working in your `web` container and docker-compose not giving any errors? if there is any errors please add them to the question.

Comment: I do not get any errors. I updated the questions accordingly.

Comment: In your webapp configuration are you exposing your host as, 127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0? What is the language and framework of webapp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record: I found a solution.

**The short answer is:** add the `--service-ports` parameter to `docker-compose run`

Example with instructions for reproduing the "problem":
https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-compose-does-not-expose-port-of-both-services-with-example-to-reproduce/94869